# How to plot a line chart from .mat file in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, simulink

Is there a simple way to plot a line chart in windows form application from .mat file generated in simulink simulation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import Matlab files, check out:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.Data.Matlab/3.0.0-alpha9

To plot the data, you've got lots of options. Free from Microsoft:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart (for Windows Forms)

A good summary of other charting options (for WPF):
[Recommendations for a Fast WPF Charting Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020271/recommendations-for-a-fast-wpf-charting-control/16180699#16180699)